# RestSharp getting result as raw bytes

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am calling an API with Restsharp.

My call is:

```
curl -H 'X-Response-Control: minified' -X GET http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions?season=2017
```

which returns a properly formed json.

With Restsharp it becomes:

```
var Client = new RestClient("http://api.football-data.org/v1");
var Request = new RestRequest($"competitions?season={DateTime.UtcNow.Year}", Method.GET);
Request.AddHeader("X-Response-Control", "minified");
var Response = Client.Execute(Request);
```

The call succeeds, but `Response.Content` is an empty string, however, `Response.RawBytes` contains the proper response.

Is it because the server doesn't identify the type of the data as text/json?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Like Hamlet your code works for me. Is this your exact code or have you put pseudo code here? I wondered if your code was in fact async and you were inspecting response content before it had finished.

Comment: It was a copy and paste, but I found that this is a problem related to how visual studio shows the info in the debugger.

Comment: It _shouldn't_ show like that in the debugger, my locals window shows the length as 3256. Admittedly I'm not sure why yours is different. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: I use VS every day and I haven't seen that before, it's quite odd; it's easy to waste time on this stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is related to visual studio:

[image]

It shows the string as empty

But when you hover:

[image]

And there is no linefeed at the beginning of the string or anything like that.